# Is it bad to feel guilty using lots of libraries?

Tags: android, source-code, libraries

So I'm an android programmer,have been programming for about 3 years,but it wasn't until 5 months ago that I started really taking it seriously. Recently I got my first internship,and I'm happy with it. The problem that I'm having is that I worry a lot about using too many libraries for certain tasks whether it be complex or simple. I tend to think,"If they can do that,maybe I can take time out of my day to learn how to do all that myself". Should I feel guilty for using "too many" libraries?

Comment: Do you think a carpenter feels guilty when they use off the shelf trusses and fasteners?

Comment: Have you received a request from someone else (either a more experienced developer, team lead, or anyone who knows your work) that you use less libraries? Have your app faced a bottleneck due to heavy use of libraries? (e.g. breakage or bugs due to a low-quality library; copyright or licensing issues; lawsuits or legal threats; app being rejected due to use of certain libraries, etc)

Comment: Questions about personal feelings is somewhat out-of-topic on Programmers.StackExchange. If this is about occupational psychology please seek professional help. *(If this is a medical emergency please hang up and dial the emergency number.)*

Comment: No, but your boss will feel bad if you waste time reinventing the wheel on his dime.

Answer (score 6):

No. As a programmer, your real job is to solve problems. Use basically any legal and ethical means at your disposal to efficiently solve the problem in a maintainable way.